# Developer Studio 12.0.0.GA fails to launch after install

Tags: jboss-developer-studio

As a pre-requisite for installing JBoss EAP 7.2, I installed the Developer Studio 12.0.0.GA successfully.
However it fails to launch with the following error:

See the error message below:

```
*jboss@rhebsr12 $> ./devstudio
***WARNING: Gtk+ version too old (micro mismatch)
***WARNING: SWT requires GTK 2.24.0
***WARNING: Detected: 2.18.9
***WARNING: SWT requires Cairo 1.9.4 or newer
***WARNING: Detected: 1.8.8
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/653/0/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-4880.so: undefined symbol: g_bus_own_name
Devstudio:
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
-jar /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio/devstudio
-name Devstudio
--launcher.library /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.700.v20180518-1200/eclipse_1705.so
-startup /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 4121001d
-product com.jboss.devstudio.core.product
-vm /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_221/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/workspace
-jar /projects/home/jboss7/devstudio/studio//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar 
/projects/home/jboss7/devstudio*
```

Any suggestions to resolve?

Thanks,
Syed

Answer (score 0):

DevStudio needs a newer version of `cairo`. I don't know which operating system you're running, but try to upgrade this package.

There is a similar issue reported here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBDS-4707